# Problem using system() to call executable application that requires user input

Tags: c++, shell

I have a simple but tricky problem. I have a C++ code that calls an executable application using `system()`.

The problem is that this executable application only ends when a key is pressed on the terminal, so when `system()` executes the application, it sticks forever because nothing happens when I click on any button.

I feel like the keyboard is binded with the C++ code, not with the application that is run.

Does anyone have any other functions to use instead of `system()` that may give me more control on the called application, or any other suggestion?

Running on Mac OS, by the way.

Comment: Consider using the language to launch another process. It will be a function of your OS. The `system()` call has very limited use in a serious C or C++ program.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`boost.process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html).

Comment: We do not know what is the `application` Try whether works `system("echo|application");`. If not then you will have to use [forkpty](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3/forkpty/).